# Reducing the execution time of a list traverser

Tags: python, algorithm, execution-time

I am working through a coding exercise. My logic makes sense but the execution limit is exceeded on a large list. This is the problem description:

> Given an array of the numbers of votes given to each of the candidates
> so far, and an integer k equal to the number of voters who haven't
> cast their vote yet, find the number of candidates who still have a
> chance to win the election.
>
> The winner of the election must secure strictly more votes than any
> other candidate. If two or more candidates receive the same (maximum)
> number of votes, assume there is no winner at all.
>
> Example
>
> For votes = [2, 3, 5, 2] and k = 3, the output should be
> electionsWinners(votes, k) = 2.
>
> The first candidate got 2 votes. Even if all of the remaining 3
> candidates vote for him, he will still have only 5 votes, i.e. the
> same number as the third candidate, so there will be no winner. The
> second candidate can win if all the remaining candidates vote for him
> (3 + 3 = 6 > 5). The third candidate can win even if none of the
> remaining candidates vote for him. For example, if each of the
> remaining voters cast their votes for each of his opponents, he will
> still be the winner (the votes array will thus be [3, 4, 5, 3]). The
> last candidate can't win no matter what (for the same reason as the
> first candidate). Thus, only 2 candidates can win (the second and the
> third), which is the answer.

This is my logic. I know that, for this problem, I have to go through each element in the list to see if adding k would make it the max value in the list.  But I also feel like I have to check the number of occurrences of that value in the list to properly identify whether there is a winner or there is a tie:

```
def electionsWinners(votes, k):
    
    # This variable basically counts the number of possible winners in the list
    counter = 0
    
    for i in votes:
        
        # If all votes go into candidate i and its not a tie:
        if k + i > max(votes) and votes.count(k + i) <= 1:
            # Increment one because we have a potential winner
            counter += 1
        
        # If there are no remaining votes and the biggest value of the list only occures once
        elif k == 0 and votes.count(max(votes)) == 1:
            
            # We only have one winner
            counter = 1
    
    return counter
```

I know that my use of `list.max()` and `list.count()` increases the execution time. What are some ways I can make this code run faster?

While I appreciate all help, it is quite frustrating to see people posting just a flat-answer. This isn't homework. Its meant for practice so you giving me the answer does not help me at all. Just let me know how to fix my existing code.  Thank you all in advance.

Comment: The value of `max(votes)` does not change and should not be calculated on every iteration.

Comment: @KlausD. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some things that can be optimised:

- `max(votes)` does not depend on the value of `i`, so it should not be evaluated in each loop iteration. Evaluate it once before the loop starts.
- The same goes for the expression `k == 0 and votes.count(max(votes)) == 1`. It does not depend on the loop variable, so it should not occur in the loop. It should become a condition that determines whether the loop should be executed or not.
- `k + i > max(votes) and votes.count(k + i) <= 1`: if the first part of the condition is true, then the second part of the condition is always true. When `k + i` is greater than the greatest in the list, that sum does *not* occur in the list at all, i.e. the count will be zero.

So taking all that together, you can write it as:

```
def electionsWinners(votes, k):
    greatest = max(votes)
    if k == 0:
        if votes.count(greatest) == 1:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0

    counter = 0
    for i in votes:
        if k + i > greatest:
            counter += 1
    
    return counter
```

You can make some tiny gains by using `sum` in stead of a "manual" `counter += 1`. At the same time code can be reduced a bit as well:

```
def electionsWinners(votes, k):
    greatest = max(votes)
    if k == 0:
        return int(votes.count(greatest) == 1)

    return sum(1 for i in votes if k + i > greatest)
```

Or even:

```
def electionsWinners(votes, k):
    mx = max(votes)
    return sum(1 for i in votes if k + i > mx) if k else int(votes.count(mx) == 1)
```